# Matplotlib plot leaks

Tags: matplotlib

I close and delete the figure and delete the sample each time, but memory use keeps growing?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
from pympler import muppy, summary
import gc
gc.enable() #enable garbage collection
def test():
    while True:
        fig = pl.figure()
        sample = 2 * np.random.random_sample((100, 1)) - 1 #noise
        pl.plot(sample)
        del sample
        pl.show()
        pl.close(fig)
        del fig
        gc.collect()
        print("Collected everything")
        # Show MemoryUsage
        all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
        sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects) #
        # Prints out a summary of the large objects
        summary.print_(sum1)
test()
```

---

Ok, this appears to release memory whenever it builds up a bit and overall memory usage remains stable.  My actual project samples audio repeatedly and uses it to control robotics.  It's meant to run non-stop, so any memory leaks will eventually crash it.

Update, this actually does slowly lose memory.  My memory usage builds and releases, but eventually builds up more and more.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
def test():
    while True:
        fig = pl.figure()
        sample = 2 * np.random.random_sample((48000, 2)) - 1 #noise
        pl.plot(sample)
        del sample
        pl.show()
        pl.close(fig)
        del fig
test()
```

I've narrowed down the problem to this, which keeps using up memory:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

def test():
    while True:
        fig = pl.figure()
        pl.close(fig)
        del fig

test()
```

without pl.close(fig)

RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).

This appears to imply that explicitly closing the figure should release memory.  If so, something is still missing from my code.  An object that can not be repeatedly created and destroyed can not be used in a program meant to run continuously.

For my project I need to be able to continuously update a plot without running out of memory.  I've tried with figure and subplot etc., but I can not figure out how to not lose memory.

Answer (score 0):

remove gc 
https://stackify.com/python-garbage-collection/

...
However, automatic memory management comes at a cost. Your program will need to use additional memory and computation to track all of its references. 
...